# how to copy SubClass object in BaseClass copy constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, copy-constructor

I would like to make copy of SubClass object in BaseClass constructor. I need that the following code execute correctly.

```
class BaseClass{
    BaseClass() {}
    BaseClass(BaseClass base) {
        //TODO: how to implement?
    }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {    
   SubClass() {}
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BaseClass sub = new SubClass();
        BaseClass subCopy = new BaseClass(sub);
        if (subCopy instanceof SubClass) {
            // need to be true
        }
    }
}
```

Is it even possible? If yes how can I do it? Else how can I get similar effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. A constructor of class A gives you an instance of A, no way to circumvent this. Why not instantiate the subclass explicitly?

Another possibility might involve a static factory method like:

```
public static BaseClass create(BaseClass input) {
       // return BaseClass or subclass
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want the object of `BaseClass` to be an instance of `SubClass` which extends `BaseClass`.

> Is it even possible?

-No. It is not possible.

The `instanceof` operator returns `true` if the variable on left side satisfies **IS-A** condition of the variable or class on the left side.

The `SubClass` **IS-A** `BaseClass` since it extends `BaseClass`. But the `BaseClass` can never be a `SubClass`, since it can't extend `SubClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be having a design upside-down. If you need to do what you are asking then you need to re-think over your design. Ideally in your subclass constructor, you should be copying or initializing the base class properties by calling super().